# loading website doesnt work is there something missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've a bootstrap template, and was just starting to alter the typing on it (not the css or html tags), and suddenly thought will this load on my hosting area, which is `1and1.co.uk`,  its doesn't.

It appears to have taken the html and not the css, despite loading up the ordinary css the other version as in css.min etc and the other one for the template.

I've loaded up the `js` and the fonts etc so there really is no reason why this shouldn't load.  is there something very obvious missing?

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what you have tried so far - it hard to tell where the failure lies by now.

Comment: wow, that for me would be all the html file, css file and js file, as i wouldnt know how to begin.  each file was loaded up separtely, and its a bootstrap template so its not exactly my own coding (not that clever!)